# Why was UAL 2013 cancelled Sept 12th 2021?

Tags: transportation, compensation, united-airlines, hotels

My flight for today, UAL (United Air Lines)  2013 from Chicago O'Hare (ORD) to Miami (MIA),  has been cancelled. Why?

I have not been rebooked until tomorrow AM. Am I entitled to any compensation?

Comment: Can you please edit in some more details?
I guess you talk about a flight which is cancelled but that is as far as I manage. To help you we will need more details, as well as full names of airlines and airports. (We can not read your mind.)

Comment: @Willeke Obviously United Airlines flight 2013 from Chicago O'Hare (ORD) to Miami International (MIA). No mind reading needed.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo It may be obvious to you. It was not to me.

Comment: Do you have travel insurance with flight delay/cancellation cover?

Answer (score 5):

> Why?

United Flights Status says

> *UA 2013: We're sorry to let you know your flight on September 12 has canceled because your plane needed to be taken out of service for maintenance. Please check out your options on the United app under the My Trips section or at https://fly.united.com/vZxXKt*.

---

> Am I entitled to any compensation?

No. From https://www.transportation.gov/individuals/aviation-consumer-protection/flight-delays-cancellations

> **My flight is delayed - am I entitled to money or other compensation from the airline?**
>
> No.  There are no federal laws requiring airlines to provide
> passengers with money or other compensation when their flights are
> delayed.  Each airline has its own policies about what it will do for
> delayed passengers.  If your flight is experiencing a long delay, ask
> airline staff if they will pay for meals or a hotel room.  While some
> airlines offer these amenities to passengers, others do not provide
> any amenities to stranded passengers.

That's substantially different in Europe, but in the US the airlines have far fewer obligations.

Comment: Whilst no compensation is legally due, for an extended delay like this caused by a mechanical issue, United's standard policy is that a hotel and meal vouchers will be provided. They will also most likely send an email offering compensation in the form of a voucher for a future flight or an amount of frequent flyer miles.

Comment: I've never understood why companies say "Sorry we messed up" by adding "Come and have another go!"